# React Navigation TabBar Active Tab

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabbar

I'm trying to create TabBar using `react-navigation` `createBottomTabNavigator`. I want to add this red thing above Tab when it's active. Any ideas how to achieve this? I was thinking about changing Tab container if it's active, but couldn't find how to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your tabs point to another stack navigators, the best idea would be to pass a custom component to tabBarIcon. Something like that:

```
SomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarButton
      isFocused={focused} // render red thing above if focused
      iconName="icon name"
    />
  ),
};
```